# lambda inner join and select all

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, lambda, selectall

Here is how I `inner join` in lambda ,

```
var myObject = tableNames.Join(tableSchool,  x => x.sID , s => s.schoolID ,  
( (x,s) => new {   }  ) ).ToList();
```

I have many fields in both `tableNames` and `tableSchool` .
By my lambda query , if I have 10 fields in `tableNames` , I've to write down all of 10 fields in `new { }` 10 times.
What I want to know is how can I select all fields of `tableName` table and one field from `tableSchool` .

Example

```
tableName     tableSchool
---------     ------------ 
Nfield1       Sfield1
Nfield2       Sfield2
Nfield3       Sfield3
Nfield4
Nfield5
```

I want to get all fields from `tableName` and just one field (Sfield1) from `tableShcool` . I want to bind this datasource to asp:GridView :)

Comment: `(x,s) => new { x, s }`?

Comment: @Oded He doesn't want to type all the fields, it seems.

Comment: That works well unless he wants a flat object, where all properties of x and s are directly accessibly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want details of both tables, then you could have:

```
List<AllDetails> myObject = tableNames.Join(tableSchool, x => x.sID, s => s.schoolID, ((x, s) => new AllDetails(x, s))).ToList();
```

where:

```
public class AllDetails
    {
        private TableName tabName;
        private TableSchool tabSchool;

        public AllDetails(TableName tableName, TableSchool tableSchool)
        {
            //Assign fields here
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand a little bit on Oded's comment. You can create a new Anonymous type in the select statement by doing:

```
(x, s) => new { x,s }
```

You can also specify the names of the items in the anonymous type by doing:

```
(x, s) => new { TableName=x,TableSchool=s }
```

If you need to use this outside of the scope of the method however, you need to use a new class such as aquaraga has suggested.

Comment: I want to bind this to `asp.net GridView` datasource .